# What is the fastest way to snap a bone to an object origin?

Tags: snapping

[image]

The GIF I took above shows how to snap bones to the origin of objects using a 3D cursor as a medium.
But at some point, I felt tired of this manipulation.

[image]

In other common modeling or placement cases, snap options on the blender help you quickly deploy elements without using a 3D cursor.
However, I couldn't find a way to place the bone at the origin of the object.

**Q : Is there a way to snap bones to the origin of the object without leaving the editing mode of the armature?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things you can do to speed things up.

First option is, assign hotkeys to snap to cursor/snap to selection.

Second option isn't actually in edit mode at all, but in pose mode.  Turn off locked object modes (in main edit menu), then select object, shift select bone, ctrl-shift-c (add constraint)-> copy location.  Don't worry about applying until you're done with all bones; when you are, select all, ctrl-a -> apply selected as rest pose, then use a "clear pose constraints" operation.

Hotkeys may vary depending on initial startup options chosen.

Neither of these is faster if you're doing a single bone.  But once you're doing it for five or more bones, they get a lot faster.